# Docker-compose Cron scheduling Python app

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, cron

Just to say that I am new to docker...
I have a docker-compose application (I like/need the docker-compose way to run multiple containers) that runs a mysql container and a python app, and I would like the python app to run every minute. I tried an infinite loop in the python code, but docker seems to prevent it from launching, so I tried with cron, but without any success (although it might not have any impact, I run docker on Windows, which seems less straightforward than on Linux :(, and use VS Code for development). Therefore, I would like to know if there is a way to use docker-compose and run the python app every minute, and if yes, how to configure cron.

my setup is the following:

- docker installed on windows.
- I run everything from VS Code' terminal, without any docker extension
- A pythonmain.py file (for example, I used emails because I could not see any logs nor print once I run the code from cron. Most likely because cron does not launch the python app):
  `

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
print("Starting Python Docker")

# EMAIL 
mail_content = "Hello"
#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = 'email1@mail.com'
sender_pass = 'pwd'
receiver_address = 'email2@mail.com'
#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'New data email.'   #The subject line
#The body and the attachments for the mail
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')

#Database
db = mysql.connect(host = 'mydb', user = 'root', password = 'root', port = 3306)
print("db connection passed")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS emails")
cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
#connect to the right database
db = mysql.connect(
    host = "mydb",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "root",
    database = "emails"
)
cursor = db.cursor()
## creating a table in database
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emailscount (id VARCHAR(255), count INT)")
## defining the Query for charger data
query = "INSERT INTO emailscount (id, count) VALUES (%s, %s)"
values = ("123",1)
cursor.execute(query, values)
db.commit()
print(cursor.rowcount, "data inserted")
```

`

- a dockerfile:
  `

```
FROM python:3.9
COPY . .
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python requests
# for implementation without cron:
# CMD ["python", "./pythonmain.py"]
# trial with cron, but python app does not launch:
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron  
RUN chmod +x pythonmain.py
RUN crontab crontab
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

`

- a crontab file:
  `

```
*/1 * * * * python ./pythonmain.py
```

`

- A docker-compose file:
  `

```
version: "3"
services:
    db:
        container_name: mydb
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    pythonapp:
        container_name: pythonapp
        depends_on:
            - "db"
        links:
            - "db"
        build: ./
        ports:
            - "5001:5000"
```

`

I would like the pythonapp to run every minute after I run the "docker-compose up" command in the terminal. But it does not work (the python app never runs, although all containers seem to be created), and I am not sure it can run as it is with the docker-compose command.
What works perfectly is when the dockerfile has the CMD ["python", "./pythonmain.py"] without everything related to *cron*, then the python app runs as it should, but of course, just once.

I tried as well to just run the python container from cron using docker build and docker run (not docker-compose up), but without any success neither, the code does not run (i.e. I was not able to replicate most of the examples/tutorials on cron for docker). Furthermore, using docker on windows, I could not find any log of error, even in the *AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data* folder (which is empty).

Obviously, I am completely new to docker, so any help would be amazing!
Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Issue is that your docker daemon starts python-container and that CMD process run - and then it is closed immediately. You need to run a never ending command for example : `tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: Your original approach of having a single long-running process without cron might be easier to set up, especially if you want the job to run as often as every minute.  You should never need to "keep the container alive" as @fly2matrix suggests; I'd expect the `cron -f` option you already have to run the cron daemon in the foreground.